# Javascript: nesting of private functions - good or bad?

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I'm frequently using this structure:

```
var example = (function () {
    function privateFn2 () {
       ...
    }
    function privateFn1 () {
       ...
    }
    return {
        publicMethod1: function () {...
        },
        publicMethod2: function () {...
        }
    };
}());
```

What I want to know is this: If privateFn1 is the only function/method that calls privateFn2, is it regarded as better practice to set it up as follows?

EDITED for clarity

```
var example = (function () {
    function privateFn1() {
        function privateFn2() {
        }
        ...
        privateFn2();
    }
    return {
        publicMethod1: function () {...
        },
        publicMethod2: function () {...
        }
    };
}());
```

This is a wildly simplified example, of course. The issue is that I have lots of private functions, and I'm wondering whether nesting is well- or poorly-regarded. I recognise it is quite possibly a matter of preference, but any advice will be gratefully received.

Thanks.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but you aren't returning the same thing.

Comment: I've edited what I mean to make it clearer. I'm pretty sure it's the same thing :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you mix function declaration styles?

Comment: Also, IMO, there is no point in nesting the private functions like that. Just keep them separated. I know you don't see any use for `privateFn2` in another function but it works the same if you keep it out of `privateFn1`. It also avoids redeclaring `privateFn2`. Also, either put the contents of `privateFn2` inside `privateFn1` instead or put `privateFn2` in the same scope as `privateFn1`.

Comment: Thanks, @TylerCrompton .  In answer to your question, I guess I mix function declaration styles because (1) there's usually no benefit in having private methods rather than functions in my case because I don't make use of `this` and so it's neater to call the function (and gets minimised smaller), and (2) the `var example = (...());` ends up being an object with methods - as I guess you realise ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the situation. If you have several private functions that are only relavent to yet another private function, then perhaps this is a situation where the object or class is packaging more functionality then it should be.

Here are some questions to ask:

- Do these private functions have side effects? That is, are they
  manipulating any closed over properties? If not, is this some generalized
  logic that could be implemented statically and included
  separately? Or, are these private functions manipulating a subset of
  properties that could be moved to another class or object?
- Are the private functions simple task specific helper functions to be used within
  a larger algorithm or control function; such as a filter function for sorting an
  array, or some other kind of iteration callback? If so, then it may be in-fact
  cleaner to nest those functions inside and keep them out of scope of the main
  object. Will any other code need these functions?
- How many times will the main private function be called? If it will be called very
  frequently (inside a loop or on a timer interval) then nesting the
  private functions inside could incur a measurable overhead -- 
  which would have otherwise been negligible had the private function
  been called only occasionally.

There are always trade-offs to consider, thinking about these questions will help you decide what is best for your particular situation.

Comment: Thanks :)  They are usually "task specific helper functions", BTW.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid your second example. Every time `privateFn1` gets called, it redefines `privateFn2`. Why not just do it once? You might even need to use it somewhere else later on.

However, if you really want to hide `privateFn2`, a better solution is this:

```
var privateFn1 = (function () {
    function privateFn2() {
        // ...
    }

    return function () {
        privateFn2();
        // ...
    };
})();
```

Comment: I omitted the outside structure in the second section of code, but I've edited it for clarity. It is already hidden by the `var example` pattern :)